# Fluid not showing in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, fluid-simulation

I made a glass and have some fluid falling into it.

I applied the fluid, smoothed it out, re sized the glass, added some ice cubes....

The glass renders and so do the ice cubes... just not the fluid!

Here are some screenshots.

Preview Render: [image]

And a sample of the final render (also taken at low quality): [image]

[As requested, here is a link to the .blend file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/t1kxc4ms3cj24ox/brennan-cup.blend)

Comment: could you [post a .blend](http://pasteall.org/blend), there are so many things that could be causing that, and it will make it much easier for us to figure out

Comment: Added .blend as requested.

Comment: If you're not a fan of mediafire download from pasteall: http://pasteall.org/blend/34619

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable rendering in the outliner

[image]

Comment: I feel so freaking stupid now. Thank you so very much! Just started learning blender for an independent project and could not for the life of me figure that out!

Comment: @BrennanM there a million tiny things that can go wrong in blender.... we all make mistakes like that

Answer (score 1):

Click the greyed out camera icon in the outliner:
[image]

To change it to this:
[image]

Comment: @BrennanM Mine and GiantCowFilms' were equally correct, and he posted his only seconds before I posted mine. :)

Comment: yup. Saw yours first, was about to mark it correct, and then gave the points to the first posted. Thank you so much for helping me in a time of facepalm though!

Comment: @BrennanM I'm here both to help and be helped. Rep points are appreciated, but not my ultimate goal. A happy customer is more important. And I upvoted the other answer, so no hard feelings. :)