# Blender render appears completely Gray

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, properties

When I hit "render" nothing appears except one object I forgot to add a material to. I'm unfamiliar with most of Blender's rendering settings. I've done some internet research but turned up largely nothing useful. I still have this problem. I've tried cycle's and the blender rendering engine. In fact this problem occurred when I switched from cycle's to blender...

For the record I am not willing to put my hard work up on here, but if you need information I can definitely post a screenshot of whatever it is that you need.

Some screenshots:

[image: The entire window]

[image: All Gray Render]

[image: My Properties Window]

Comment: Ecah render engine currently needs it's own material definitions. You can't switch from one to another easily (though there are some plug in that can help). See related question: [Does Switching From Blender Render To Cycles Mess Things Up?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/does-switching-from-blender-render-to-cycles-mess-things-up)

Comment: Enable the camera icon in the outliner to make the objects renderable http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26181/1853

Answer (score 1):

Go back into your material settings on the objects not being rendered and turn off Use Shader Nodes, if you are rendering in the Blender Internal render instead of Cycles.  This selection is next to the Material Text box just above the Surface / Wire /  Volume / Halo buttons and to the right. of the text box.

Comment: I'll try that, but I'm kinda busy at the moment with other things! Sorry I didn't get back sooner, this is just a personal project and takes a back seat to other thins especially right now!!! :)

Comment: I think I actually just ended up deleting all of the materials once back in Blender Render. I'm not entirely sure what I did though. That is good information to know though!